# breaking down an input sentence

Tags: c++, string

in the code i am working on, the input will be of this form: abcd = insert(15MB). What i need to do is insert 15MB into the identifier 'abcd'. Here is the code i have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;



string extract(string pMem);
double toByte(int phyMem, string val);

string pMem, comment, sGen, val,foo;
int gen, phyMem, i=0, oBrckt=0, cBrckt=0;
double pmemSize =0;

int main()
{
 getline(cin,foo);     

  if((foo.find("insert"))!= string::npos)
    cout<<"Found insert"<<endl;

  cin.clear();


}
```

The problem: I am unable to find the code word insert from the input command. I am guessing the problem is because the word insert(15MB) is considered as a whole. Is there any way to break it down so that i can save abcd into the identifier "tag", and 50MB into the identifier "Memory"?

Comment: Well I can tell you that the problem is NOT because the word insert(15MB) is considered as a whole. string::find returns the first occurrence of that *sequence*.

Comment: `std::find` is the right tool for the job, it can locate substrings just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that `insert` word is present before the next line character in the sequence ?

Comment: [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Comment: Your code actually works (finds "insert"), but it reads from the standard input. If you are unable to trigger the "Found Insert" code, you might be trying to provide input from another source, such as command line arguments.

Comment: @Mahesh The format is abcd = insert(15MB); I missed out the semicolon.

Comment: Hmm let me verify again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `scanf`, which is faster than cin and also provides the functionality you want:

```
char t[256], m[256];
scanf("%s = insert(%[^)]);", t, m);
string tag = t, Memory = m;
```

This basically means: *read a string, then skip " = insert(", then read the inner string until you find a ')', then skip the final ");".*

Just make sure you are reading from the correct input.

If you really want to read the input with `getline`, you can still use `sscanf` to achieve the same, on top of your `foo` string:

```
sscanf(foo.c_str(), "%s = insert(%[^)]);", t, m);
```

Note the extra 's' in `sscanf` is not a typo here. `t` and `m` are just temporary char buffers to store your content, you can assign it directly to a string afterwards if you wish. Please note the code above assumes the 'tag' and 'Memory' contents will not be longer than 255 characters each.